# Servlet doGet() is not updating

Tags: java, servlets

I have simple Srvlet class with following Get method:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Hello from Get method");
}
```

When I try to run this on Tomcat server , 8.5, I get the following message on browser : "Served at: /SimpleServletProject". This was the message which i removed from the default implementation of the Servlet.
And nothing is getting printed on Console. 
Somehow my changes are not reflecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this one**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        System.out.println("Hello from Get method");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml you should map your servlet like

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>full path of class</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/url</url-pattern>
```